# $geoWithin gives "unknown GeoJSON type" error

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to learn MongoDB for one of my classes and using the zips dataset (http://media.mongodb.org/zips.json), I am trying to find zips within these points: [ -80 , 30 ] , [ -90 , 30 ] , [ -90 , 40 ] and [ -80 , 40 ].

After referring to docs [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/geoWithin/#examples)

I came up with this query:

```
 db.zips.find({loc: {$geoWithin : {$geometry : {type : "polygon", coordinates : [[[-80, 30], [-90, 30], [-90, 40], [-80, 40], [-80, 30]]]}}}})
```

I thought it would work but I get the following error:

```
Error: error: {
    "waitedMS" : NumberLong(0),
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "unknown GeoJSON type: { type: \"polygon\", coordinates: [ [ [ -80.0, 30.0 ], [ -90.0, 30.0 ], [ -90.0, 40.0 ], [ -80.0, 40.0 ], [ -80.0, 30.0 ] ] ] }",
    "code" : 2
}
```

What is the right way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that you use the wrong geo type, it should be `Polygon` try:

```
db.zips.find({
  loc: {
    $geoWithin: {
      $geometry: {
        type: "Polygon",
        coordinates: [
          [
            [
              -80, 30
            ],
            [
              -90, 30
            ],
            [
              -90, 40
            ],
            [
              -80, 40
            ],
            [-80, 30]
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  }
})
```